# JSON.stringify() vs array.join(',')

Tags: javascript, json, string, asp.net-web-api, serialization

In `Angular 6`, I was using `myString.join(',')` to join an array of IDs into one long string of comma separated IDs.

When I would send this to the `.NET Web API`, I noticed only one value, the first ID, was being sent. I then fixed this on the front end by changing `myString.join(',')` to `JSON.stringify(myString.join(','))`. Now, on the API, all of the ID's are sent successfully.

I was wondering why this is. I understand that data needs to be sent via `JSON`, but what is the difference between a `JSON` string and a front end Typescript string built by `.join(',')`? I kind of expected just a regular `.join()` to work, since it is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `array.prototype.join` and `JSON.stringify` return simple strings. So you should be able to console log the two and find the distinction for your input.

Most likely, its quotation marks. `JSON.stringify(string)` wraps `string` in quotes `"` and escapes existing quotes.

```js
let s = '""yo i already have many quotes"""';
let j = JSON.stringify(s);
console.log(s);
console.log(j);
```

```js
let ids = [123, 516];
let idsJoin = ids.join(',');
let idsJson = JSON.stringify(idsJoin);

console.log(ids);
console.log(idsJoin);
console.log(idsJson);
```

Comment: Ah, you're correct. My array of ID's logs as `[ID1, ID2]`, myString.join(',') logs as `ID1, ID2` and json.stringify(myString.join(',')) logs as `'ID1, ID2'`.

So I guess I need both. Thanks @Junvar

Comment: I'm surprised that myString.join(',') doesn't wrap it in quotes, since it's supposed to be a string, right? Why is that?

Comment: `['a', 'b', 10, true].join(',')` returns the string `"a,b,10,true"`. It neither adds spaces, nor wraps the string in quotes, as that's not part it's purpose. I think you're confusing *returns a string* with *wraps in quotes*, which are two distinct actions. Strings can exist without them being wrapped in quotes, e.g. `'hello'` v `'"hello"'`.

Comment: Yes, they produce similar results in this case, but it's easy to become confused, as this question demonstrates, when you don't separate them conceptually. Serialization should not be used to concatenate and vice versa.  rather, choose the correct tool based on what you're trying to accomplish